# Why am I missing 2 required positional arguments when I did add them to the function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have tried changing the variable to an integer within the function but that didn't work. I would prefer to not make it a global function either.

```
# Finds the max size of another angle in the triangle

side1 = input("First side:  ")
side2 = input("Second side:  ")

side1 = int(side1)
side2 = int(side2)

def nextEdge(side1, side2):
    maxLength = (side1 + side2)
    return maxLength

nextEdge()

print(maxLength)
```

Comment: You are missing the 2 required arguments here: `nextEdge()`. Add them into that function call.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling nextEdge without any parameters. Your call to nextEdge should look like:

```
maxLength = nextEdge(side1, side2)
```